# Pulling a property from a filtered array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array (see below), which I am pulling a specific object from by filtering it by evaluating the result of the `comp_group` property.

**So, in the view:**

```
<p>Standings array for this team: {{getStandings | filter: {team_id: "1"} }}</p>
```

**And the `getStandings` array looks like this:**

```
         [  
            {  
              "comp_group":"Group A",
              "team_id":"1",
              "team":"A",
              "overall_w":"0",
              "overall_l":"0",
           },
           {  
              "comp_group":"Group A",
              "team_id":"2",
              "team":"B",
              "overall_w":"0",
              "overall_l":"0",
           },
           {  
              "comp_group":"Group B",
              "team_id":"3",
              "team":"C,
              "overall_w":"0",
              "overall_l":"0",
           },
           {  
              "comp_group":"Group B",
              "team_id":"4",
              "team":"D,
              "overall_w":"0",
              "overall_l":"0",
           }
        ]
```

This successfully pulls the first object from the array (the one with `team_id: 1`).

However, I don't know how to access *that object's individual properties* in an angular expression.

**My (unsatisfactory) solution:**

Since the result is an array containing a single object, my current solution is to do ng-repeat with the filter on each element, and then pull the property from that, but it is very repetitious and clearly not the best solution.

Looks like this:

```
<table>
    <col width="210px">
    <col width="">
    <tr ng-repeat="teamstat in getStandings | filter: {team_id: whichMyteam} ">
        <td><p>Games Played:</p></td>
        <td><p>{{teamstat.overall_gp}}</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="teamstat in getStandings | filter: {team_id: whichMyteam} ">
        <td><p>Wins:</p></td>
        <td><p>{{teamstat.overall_w}}</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="teamstat in getStandings | filter: {team_id: whichMyteam} ">
        <td><p>Draws:</p></td>
        <td><p>{{teamstat.overall_d}}</p></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Is there a more elegant way to go about this?

Comment: Could you show what table formating you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

do to this with only one ng-repeat you can place your ng-repeat on a tbody tag

```
<table>
    <col width="210px">
    <col width="">
    <tbody ng-repeat="teamstat in getStandings | filter: {team_id: whichMyteam} ">
       <tr>
           <td><p>Games Played:</p></td>
           <td><p>{{teamstat.overall_gp}}</p></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><p>Wins:</p></td>
           <td><p>{{teamstat.overall_w}}</p></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><p>Draws:</p></td>
           <td><p>{{teamstat.overall_d}}</p></td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: That helps clean it up a lot, thanks (surprised I didn't think of that...) . However, I'm still using ng-repeat, and it doesn't seem the right situation since nothing is repeating. In my situation I just need to access those properties in the array, and currently ng-repeat is the only way I can think to do it...

Comment: yes i understand. For me ng-repeat is a correct way to do what you expect but maybe it's more the render that you done. Table tag and ng-repeat can be difficult to manipulate. For my apps i used div with bootstrap tab css to render it to the users.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure, you will get at most one object by filtering then you can assign the filtered object to a variable.

You can use ng-init in somewhere(before printing from variable) of template to initialize a variable with the filtered object.

```
<p ng-init='teamstat = (getStandings | filter: {team_id: "1"})'>Standings array for this team: {{getStandings}}</p>
```

But, initializing in template like this, makes code unreadable and difficult to maintain. So, instead of the above solution, use filter in controller and initialize the variable there.

Controller :

```
$scope.teamstat = $filter('filter')($scope.getStandings, {team_id: "1"})[0];
```

Don't forget to inject $filter in your controller.

Then, show teamstat in the view.

```
<table>
    <col width="210px">
    <col width="">

    <tr>
        <td><p>Games Played:</p></td>
        <td><p>{{teamstat.overall_gp}}</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p>Wins:</p></td>
        <td><p>{{teamstat.overall_w}}</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p>Draws:</p></td>
        <td><p>{{teamstat.overall_d}}</p></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```